# MongoDB aggregation - match performance

Tags: performance, mongodb, match

match clause in mongo db aggregation:
E.g

```
db.articles.aggregate(
    [ { $match : { author : "dave" } } ]
);
```

I have many records in database, What if we do not specify any condition in match clause? Does it affect the performance issue?

Comment: Why would you not specify a condition in the match clause?

Comment: It is parameter based, so if any parameter are received it goes in match, otherwise not.

Comment: ok, but if you don't specify a condition it will retrive all the documents, so, what is your question about?

Comment: Do you have an index on `author`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it affect the performance if my result set is bigger? **Yes** (eye opening answer, right ;-) )

You need to fetch all the data from disk and load it into memory (if it's not already in memory), and you definitely need to send more data over the network.

If you don't have a condition to match on, you should probably add a limit to the number of returned results (or provide a method to limit+offset them)